# video-audio calling through website using api on php

Tags: php, audio

How do I Put Video/Audio Call Facility On My Website? I have a website and I want register users to call other users of my website. What API to use ? Is there any API that can facilitate me in this?

Plus I am using php.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Check out a script called Magnoliyan Video Chat pro.

Comment: Maybe: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/ or http://www.skype.com/en/developer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Magnoliyan Video Chat PRO](http://www.magnoliyan.com/video-chat-pro/)** is the first HTML5/PHP video chat solution. PRO Edition allows group chat, file transfer and chat roulette mode.

[image]

> **Magnoliyan Video Chat PRO** (mgVideoChat) is full featured video communication system with integrated text chat available directly
>   within your web browser. You can consider it as online web based
>   Skype, but without the requirement to install any additional software,
>   plugin nor flash.
>
> There is unlimited number of use cases: online live video chat
>   support, private rooms, community chat rooms...
>
> Compared to standard Video Chat, PRO version features: group
>   (conference) video chat, file transfer, chat roulette mode
>
> Unlike some other systems, Magnoliyan Video Chat PRO includes full
>   featured server side "signaling" engine: you can see who is online,
>   click to call, click to end call, send text messages. You can even
>   mark certain users as operators which are able to receive calls while
>   all others can just make calls.
>
> There is special plugin system for authorization php classes but
>   Magnoliyan Video Chat PRO comes with built in support for facebook
>   login and wordpress accounts. It's even possible to use different
>   authorization system per chat room.

Comment: thanq friend. actually i don't know much about this video/audio calling so just thought of asking the question here. as stack-over flow is a trustworthy site. thnq for help.. please dont vote down my question

Comment: why is my question on hold by you?

Comment: @MiliBiswas It is not on hold by me. It is on hold by 5 of other people, because this is not a type of question that can be asked at StackOverflow.